# Yii: передача данных в слой

Tags: php, yii

Есть:

- Модель описывающая дерево регионов
     нашей необъятной
- Модель
     дополнительных объектов для каждого
     региона
- Контролер который делает из
     этих моделей вложенные списки

Хочу оформить этот список как всплывающее окно, но в упор не понимаю, как делать рендеринг слоя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->renderPartial('sloy',array('data'=>$data));
```

Ну ачто у тебя и как в слое будет это уже твои дела

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, речь идет о layout?

В большинстве случаев удобно оформить как виджет.

Если контент зависит от данных, полученых в контроллере, добавьте в Controller (класс, наследуемый от CController атрибут типа $layoutData, в него и собирайте информацию), а в самом layout либо прямой вывод с использованием этих данных ($this->controller->layoutData), лиюбо вызывайте виджет, передавая layoutData ему